# Generate Keycloak Offline Token

Tags: keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, bearer-token

I am new to Keycloak identity and user management.
I am primarily looking for a method to generate offline token.

Currently I have
Authorization URL, Access Token Request & Refresh Token Request
In order to generate offline tokens we need to add additional parameter as **scope=offline_access**
I am not sure why in my case it is not getting generated as I have validated the bearer token from jwt.io the "typ" is not "offline".

The access token request is

```
curl \  
 -d "client_id=<my-client-id>" -d "client_secret=<client-secret>" \  
 -d "username=<user>" -d "password=<pass>" \
 -d "grant_type=password" \
 -d "scope=openid info offline_access" \   
 https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token | jq

Method: POST
URL: https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
Body type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Form fields:    
client_id : <my-client-name>
grant_type : refresh_token
refresh_token: <my-refresh-token>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Can you please post the exact outcome of your curl request? Per default, there is no scope `info` in Keycloak. What makes you think the `typ` in your token should be `offline`?

Comment: The outcome is null.If the typ is not offline then how can I verify the token to be offline refresh token. Could you please help me with the keycloak configurations and some curl /postman endpoints with parameters to generate the offline token.

Comment: Try this to check if you could get an offline token for your master realm and admin-cli client: `curl -d "client_id=admin-cli" -d "username=<your admin username>" -d "password=<your admin password>" -d "grant_type=password" -d "scope=openid offline_access"  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token | jq`

That should work ootb with Keycloak. (tested with 13 and 14).